# Custom Module Header Class Css

Tags: joomla-3.5, custom-module, module-style

i am developing an web site in Joomla, and i wolud like adding a css class to my custom module. Specifically to an h3 tag. But when i have wrotten the css class into the form input field in the Advanced Tab and i save this change, it isn't registered and consecuently this change isn't displayed into the browser.

[image]

How i could to solve this problem?

Comment: Clear the browser cache and the joomla! cache.

Comment: Explaining how you are implementing your custom CSS and showing us your CSS code might help.

Comment: I to solve this partially, via template.css:        .text-contact-heading h3{
  color: #555555;
}

Comment: But i would like to do this through the Header Class Input displayed  in de above form

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot you put your class name into "Module Class Suffix". Suffix is a keyword there, because in you case it will give you a class name:

```
customlatestnews
```

in the HTML code of the website. There is a simple trick however - just add a whitespace before class name in Module Class Suffix field.

If this is custom-developed module, ensure that it use the 'moduleclass_sfx' parameter, like (in main module file):

```
$moduleclass_sfx = htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'));
```

And then:

```
class="someclassname<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>"
```

In module's /tmpl/default.php (or any other layout).